# When I use send_keys Chrome cant receive all tags (XML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber

I have a textbox and I'm using `find_element` command and `send_keys` to send XML but the problem is, when I send XML, Chrome doesn't receive all the tags as if it were very fast to receive and just missed the letters.

```
@browser.find_element(:xpath,'/html/body/form/textarea').send_keys(@xml)
@browser.find_element(:xpath,'//*[@id="BotaoEnviar"]').click
```

Example XML (taken from comment):

```
<Xml> 
    <Id>123456</Id> 
    <Card>1234567890</Card> 
    <Value>15000</Value> 
</Xml>
```

**error**

```
<Xml> 
    <Id>123456</Id> 
    <Card>1234567890</crtao> 
    <Value>15000</vaor> 
</Xml>
```

Comment: I can not share the xml, but the xml it's all ok. The problem is when the chrome will receive letters

Comment: Can you provide a short, simplified version of the XML which still replicates your problem? If you add a `sleep` between those lines, does that change the behaviour?

Comment: it sends all tags correctly, the problem is that it fills very fast to textarea, sometimes going all tags, or missing one letter in a tag.


`Example:
<Xml>
<Id> 123456 <id>
<Card> 1234567890 </ Card>
<Value> 15000 </ value>
</ Xml>

error
<Xml>
<Id> 123456 <id>
<Card> 1234567890 </ crtao>
<Value> 15000 </ vaor>
</ Xml>`

Comment: How bizarre.... Is this test running locally, or for example on Jenkins? What browser (inc. version) and selenium webdriver version are you using? A quick google search shows [other people](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/698) are experiencing similar issues, and it may be something to do with X11 forwarding.

Comment: I'm testing local and using `selenium-Webdriver-2.53.4`
and chrome `version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)`

Comment: @Pandinhabrc the comments is not a place to add information to your post I updated your question with the XML although I did clean up formatting e.g. (`<Id></ id>` Changed to `<Id></Id>`) as I am assuming your comment was incorrect if not please edit the post and set the formatting back.

Comment: No problems I wrote wrong, but the error is still in the form in which the chrome receive. Because sometimes will when the chrome gets "slowly" xml